# Not able to assign elastic ip using knife

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I want to create a EC2 instance using knife with an elastic IP assigned to it. Knife has the option `--associate-eip` but when I use this option it fails with error

> ERROR: Elastic IP requested is not available.

even though the EIP in AWS console shows the IP is available.

The command I executed

> knife ec2 server create -S testKey -I ami-e7b8c0d7 --security-group-id test_sg -N test-eip -f m3.medium --region us-west-2 -i testKey.pem --associate-eip 6.6.6.6

Did I miss any obvious steps? Where does knife look for the elastic ip list? Is there a place to inform about the elastic IP list to knife?

Comment: Have you read this thread? https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/KNIFE-151

Answer (score 1):

After adding the `--subnet` attribute with the default subnet id of that region and adding `--server-connect-attribute public_ip_address`, its possible to create instances with eip assigned.

> knife ec2 server create -N test-eip -I ami-e7b8c0d7 --security-group-id sg-685a00d -f m3.medium --region us-west-2 --ssh-user ubuntu -S testKey -i key.pem --associate-eip 6.6.6.6 --subnet  --server-connect-attribute public_ip_address

To find the default subnetid of the region, launch the instance and in the "Configure Instance Details" take subnet id that is displayed.